# Issue installing Handlebars.js with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am having an issue installing handlebars with Node npm, and in general understanding how to use require() in general.

It appears that the Handlebars module is not installed at all.

Within WebStorm terminal I installed the following successfully:

npm install handlebars

npm install require

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Todo App: Vanilla JS, Bootstrap, Handlebars</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="shoesNav">
        <script id="body-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
            {{#each this}}
                <li class="shoes">{{name}} -- Price: {{price}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </script>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
        var shoesData = [{name:"Nike", price:199.00 }, {name:"Loafers", price:59.00 }, {name:"Wing Tip", price:259.00 }];
        //Get the HTML from the template   in the script tag​
        var theTemplateScript = document.getElementById("body-template").innerHTML;
        alert(theTemplateScript);
        //Compile the template​
        var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
        document.getElementsByClassName("shoesNav")[0].appendChild(theTemplate);

        //We pass the shoesData object to the compiled handleBars function​
        // The function will insert all the values from the objects in their respective places in the HTML and returned HTML as a string. Then we use jQuery to append the resulting HTML string into the page​
    </script>
</body>
</html>

├─┬ handlebars@4.0.5
│ ├── async@1.5.0
│ ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│ │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
│ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
│ ├─┬ source-map@0.4.4
│ │ └── amdefine@1.0.0
│ └─┬ uglify-js@2.6.1
│   ├── async@0.2.10
│   ├── source-map@0.5.3
│   ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│   └─┬ yargs@3.10.0
│     ├── camelcase@1.2.1
│     ├─┬ cliui@2.1.0
│     │ ├─┬ center-align@0.1.2
│     │ │ ├─┬ align-text@0.1.3
│     │ │ │ ├─┬ kind-of@2.0.1
│     │ │ │ │ └── is-buffer@1.1.0
│     │ │ │ ├── longest@1.0.1
│     │ │ │ └── repeat-string@1.5.2
│     │ │ └── lazy-cache@0.2.7
│     │ ├─┬ right-align@0.1.3
│     │ │ └─┬ align-text@0.1.3
│     │ │   ├─┬ kind-of@2.0.1
│     │ │   │ └── is-buffer@1.1.0
│     │ │   ├── longest@1.0.1
│     │ │   └── repeat-string@1.5.2
│     │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│     ├── decamelize@1.1.1
│     └── window-size@0.1.0
└─┬ require@2.4.20
  ├── std@0.1.40
  └─┬ uglify-js@2.3.0
    ├── async@0.2.10
    ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
    │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
    └─┬ source-map@0.1.43
      └── amdefine@1.0.0
```

Comment: The [require module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require) doesn't work like you think it works. `require` is a function built-in to Node.js and works when you're running it on the server. If you want to use Handlebars client side, you'll need to add a `<script>` tag with the `src` pointing to handlebars to use it. If you want to use `require`, consider using something like [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD syntax (like `require`) is not supported by browsers.

You have installed modules designed to run within Node.JS, not embedded in an HTML document and served up to a browser.

Tools like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/) let you use AMD modules in a browser (providing they don't depend on features not supported by browsers).

Alternatively, you could get a version of handlebars designed for use in a browser by following the [install instructions](http://handlebarsjs.com/installation.html) for a bower or manual install.